# Jax ws rs filter

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I am trying to write a filter to filter calls to my web services. I am using WAS 8.5 java ee 6 compilant application server.

I searched online and found that there are two interfaces `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter`. I tried to implement these interfaces and found that these interfaces are not part of javaee 6 jax ws rs specification.

Can any one please tell me how do I filter the requests and responses in a java ee 6 environment.

We are using jersey as the jax ws rs implementation. I don't want to use any jersey specific classes because we want to migrate the code to `JBoss`, where we will use rest easy as the implementation.

Comment: The name of the component is JAX-RS not "jax ws rs" :)

Answer (score 1):

The specific Java EE 6 way is through implementing the **javax.servlet.Filter interface** and then annotating your  class with the **javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter** annotation.

You can see the docs right here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;

@WebFilter(filterName = "TimeOfDayFilter",
urlPatterns = {"/*"},
initParams = {
    @WebInitParam(name = "mood", value = "awake")})
public class TimeOfDayFilter implements Filter {
    ....
```

However, I don't see any reason why implementing ContainerRequestFilter or ContainerResponseFilter and registering it in your web.xml wouldn't work just as well.

Comment: Only option in the EE 6 world

Comment: @peeskillet, it looks like you'd know better than me :).